# How to get auto generated id From jpa repo after saving data?

Tags: java, jpa

```
public TargetGroup createTargetGroup( ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TargetGroup tg=new TargetGroup();
        targetGroups.add(tg);
        targetGroupRepository.save(tg);
        return tg;
    }
```

How do i get the id of tg ? i am getting NullPointerException while accessin it

Comment: "coz" is not a word and you shouldn't use it if you want many people to understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if entity is properly configured to generate id, you can take object returned by save method.

```
tg=targetGroupRepository.save(tg);
```

Comment: the value that is being returned is null

Comment: its getting the id fine something wrong in the controller

Comment: @PostMapping("/createTargetGroup")
   public String createTargetGroup(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute(name = "filterDetails") FilterDetails filterDetailsObj,
    BindingResult result) { 
    TargetGroup targetGroup=new TargetGroup();
    targetGroup=  socService.createTargetGroup();
    customers = socService.filterDetails(filterDetailsObj);
    socService.addTargetGroupCustomers(customers,targetGroup);
    socService.addTargetGroupFilters(filterDetailsObj,targetGroup);
    model.addAttribute("targetgroup",targetGroup);
    return "welcome";
    
  
}

Comment: i get null pointer exception where i m using targetGroup=socService.createTargetGroup()

Comment: U should open another question however if socService is null it's not injected check how it's wired